# JInternalFrame activate/deactivate events fired multiple times

Tags: java, windows, swing, look-and-feel, jinternalframe

In my application, in a JDesktopPane I have added few JInternalFrames. Activation and deactivation of JInternalFrames happen normally, until one of the JInternalFrame is maximized. After that, activating an internalframe programmatically, fires internalFrameActivated, internalFrameDeactivated events multiple times. Why it is called many times? This I have observed in WindowsLookAndFeel only

```
public class IFTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowsLookAndFeel());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane();

    JInternalFrame if1 = new JInternalFrame("IF1");
    JInternalFrame if2 = new JInternalFrame("IF2");
    if1.setTitle("IF1");
    if2.setTitle("IF2");

    pane.add(if1);
    pane.add(if2);

    frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    if1.setMaximizable(true);
    if1.setSize(400, 400);
    showInternalFrame(if1);
    if1.addInternalFrameListener(new MyInternalFrameListener("IF1"));

    if2.setMaximizable(true);
    if2.setSize(300, 300);
    if2.setVisible(true);
    showInternalFrame(if2);
    if2.addInternalFrameListener(new MyInternalFrameListener("IF2"));
    System.out.println("------------------------------");

    try {
        if1.setMaximum(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    showInternalFrame(if2);
}

static class MyInternalFrameListener extends InternalFrameAdapter {

    String name;

    public MyInternalFrameListener(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.println(name + " activated");
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.println(name + " iconfied");

    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.println(name + " deactivated");
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        System.out.println(name + " deiconfied");
    }
}

public static void showInternalFrame(JInternalFrame intf) {
    try {
        if (intf.isIcon())
            intf.setIcon(false);

        intf.setVisible(true);
        intf.moveToFront();
        intf.setSelected(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: maybe you are right, for better help sooner post an SSCCEm short, runnable, compilable to avoiding speculations about JInternalFrames events

Comment: There are some, interesting, behaviours of the desktop manager implementation under windows.  We stole the default desktop manager and replaced it under the windows look and feel

Comment: @MadProgrammer please this is answer to OP or not :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I don't have the code at hand, so I can't be 100%, but had some seriously weird behaviour with maximised windows :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for confirm me it

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is called many times?

I would guess that it doesn't like to have multiple frames maximized at one time. In a normal GUI you would have to restore the currently maximized frame before you could click on another frame to maximizing it.

Your code is:

```
if1.setMaximum(true);
showInternalFrame(if2);
```

I noticed that after executing this code, if2 is maximized even though you did not explicitly ask for it to be maximized. So I'm guessing that somewhere in the code to select a frame it realizes that the current frame is maximized so there is a bunch of code that is executing that restores/deactivates the frames a couple of time until if1 is restored and if2 is selected and maximized. The code is obviously generating a bunch of events as it does this.

On the other hand if you have code like:

```
if1.setMaximum(true);
if1.setMaximum(false);
showInternalFrame(if2);
```

then you get the events as expected.

So maybe as a solution to your problem you can add code like the following in your showInternalFrame() method:

```
JinternalFrame active = intf.getDesktopPane().getSelectedFrame();

if (active.isMaximized())
    active.setMaximum(false);

ints.setSelected(true);
```